# Makeing a bootable iso file smaller

Tags: windows, usb, iso-image

I have a USB flash-drive with some bootable iso's on it and i need a way to make them smaller they must keep the iso file extension and they must be bootable just like they were before. Does any one know how i could do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might depend on the OS used?

Comment: @Peter Windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MagicISO](http://www.magiciso.com) has its [UIF format](http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/miso-whatuif.htm) and [PowerISO](http://www.poweriso.com) has a [DAA](http://www.poweriso.com/tutorials/what-is-daa-file.htm) format. Both image formats can be mounted without extracting, but are not be bootable.

Most ISO tools let you "compress" an ISO file, such as [described here for MagicISO](http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/miso-compressiso.htm). I'm not sure what that does exactly, but you could try that.

Bottom line: bootable ISO images have very limited options in terms of compression.